# Show the selected value when using html.dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Selects, new SelectList(Model.Selects, "Value", "Text", Model.Select), "Select"})`
```

for a dropdown to show the list of US states. The text I am showing is AL Alabama,CA California,NY New York etc....See below

```
<option value="AL">AL Alabama</option>
<option value="CA">CA California</option>
<option value="NY">NY New York</option>
....
```

The value attribute has the state abbreviation. What I want to achieve is, when the selection is made by the user the selected value on the UI should show the state abbreviation and not the state name. Currently it is showing abbreviation state name. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to simply use your Value property twice (both as a value of an option and as an inner text):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Selects, 
    new SelectList(Model.Selects, "Value", "Value", Model.Select), "Select"})
```

In case you would firstly like to show the state name and then only after the selection of a user change it into the state abbrevation you should handle this via Javascript.

To do this via Javascript you should firstly set the id of your drop-down-list and assign appropriate `onChange` function:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Selects, 
    new SelectList(Model.Selects, "Value", "Text", Model.Select), "Select"},
    , new {@id="selectListId" onchange = "setText(this)"})
```

Then implement your function:

```
function setText(sel) {
   var selectedItem = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
   selectedItem.text = selectedItem.value;  
   //or       
   //$("#selectListId option:selected").text(selectedItem.value); 
}
```

Comment: Any hint on how to achieve this using javascript?